# Fastboot doesn't recognize my Asus zenfone2 on my ubuntu14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, udev, fastboot, lsusb

On the normal boot mode, my  Asus zenfone2(ZE551ML) running android 5.0 is listed when I type `adb devices`. Then, I put the phone to the fastboot mode by `adb boot bootloader`.
When the phone is already entering the fastboot mode, `fastboot devices` returns no result. But, `lsusb` listed the device's details including vendorid, productid, and device name.

I have tried to modified the 51-android.rule, run fastboot as root, change owner of the /dev/bus/usb/, re-install and update the android-tools. But my ubuntu still can not detect the zenfone2 on fastboot mode.

Moreover, I connect my other phone(Redmi2) which also on fastboot mode and it can be detected seamlessly. Also,when I tried to connect the zenfone2 to other ubuntu PC, it can be detected.

Has anyone ever encountered and solved the similar problem?
Or perhaps have an idea what is the potential cause?

Comment: try run your fastboot with sudo

Comment: I have tried to run with sudo, doesnt work as well.

Comment: Can you see the phone when running `lsusb`?

Comment: @scottt yes, it listed out my zenfone2 vendorid:productid and the name.

Comment: The fact that the same Zenphone in fastboot mode can be detected when plugged into another computer is useful. Compare 1. fastboot version 2. Ubuntu distro version 3. Linux kernel version 4. USB host controller hardware on the computer between the two computers. Maybe try plugging the Zenphone in a USB hub.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. Solved replacing my installed `fastboot` by the one in:

https://github.com/simmac/minimal_adb_fastboot